# log4j: Class name showing in log is not correct when I call the logger from another class

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Basically, when using log4j, I know we have to initiate a Logger by using Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class) or Logger.getLogger("MyClass").

I have too many classes and I dont want to add this statement in every class. Rather, what I woudl like to do is this

```
Logger.info(this,"My message");
```

Where Logger is a class I have written (not the one in log4j) which in turn initiates an object of type Logger (org.apache.log4j.Logger) and carries on with the message.

This is my Logger.java

```
package com.mypackage;

/**
 * @author Sriram Sridharan
 *Custom logging implementation using log4j
 */
public class Logger {
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger;

    /**
     * Writes an INFO log
     * @param oClass
     * @param message
     */
    public static void INFO(Object oClass, String message){

org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(oClass.getClass());
    logger.info(message);
}
}
```

Now, I have my own class, that calls this Logger implementation to log events. it looks like this

```
public class MyClass {

    public void myMethod(){
        com.mypackage.Logger.INFO(this, "Hello, World");
    }
}
```

I don't have a problem with the logs. They're fine. However, the Class name displayed in the logs is the same (Logger). This is the output

```
 INFO [main] (Logger.java:18) - Hello, World
```

I expect this

```
 INFO [main] (MyClass.java:18) - Hello, World
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is printed seems to be the location where the call to info() is made (you should post your pattern to confirm). And it's done from Logger.java, line 18, so it's quite expected. By the way, the Logger.INFO() method doesn't use its first argument at all.

Comment: Even though this might not be what you want to hear: you already answered your question. The problem is that you are calling the logger that belongs to another class..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `%c` pattern to output category /`getLogger("myCategory")`/ instead of `%C` that prints caller class.

The idea is that you have generic method:

```
public static void debug(String category, String message) {
    Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(category);
    logger.debug(message);
}
```

and your log4j configuration contains your pattern:

```
%d{ISO8601} %c %m %n
```

and this will print

```
2014-02-21 14:38:120 YourCategory Your Message
```

So you do not need to mess up with instatiation of Logger for each class with log.

Comment: Its working good. But if I have to show line number too from that class from which call was initiated then it is not happening using current technique(one logger obj class) but it will always show same line number at which very last, logger.info(message) method is invoked. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `logger.info(message);` inside `Logger class` so always `Logger.java` you will get in your log file.

You can log the message inside the class in which you want to log, the classname will be logged.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the class parameter in obtaining the log4j logger, so log4j assumes your logger class.
Try

```
public static void INFO(Object oClass, String message){
   org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(oClass.getClass());
   logger.info(message);
}
```

instead.

Comment: I tried using oClass.getClass(), but still I get the same result.