# Generic logger in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using a generic class(`LoggerUtils.java`) for logging messages in my code. There is a constructor which accepts Class as argument and all the other classes call this to initialize a logger object. I am using slf4j. But my problem is when I view the log, the log displays class name as `LoggerUtils` in all the logs. I need to see the class from where I called the `LoggerUtils` class for displaying my log. Is there any way of doing it?

Log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.SampleLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SampleLog.File=/sample.log 
log4j.appender.SampleLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.SampleLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} (%c: %M %L) - %m%n 
log4j.category.com.sample=DEBUG, SampleLog
```

LoggerUtils.java

```
    package com.sample.utils;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


    public class LoggerUtils {

        private Logger logger;

        private  LoggerUtils(Class clazz) {
            try {
                logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in logger");
            }
        }

        public static LoggerUtils getLogger(Class clazz) {
            return new LoggerUtils(clazz);
        }

        public void info(Object message) {
            logger.info(message.toString());
        }
    }


My Sample Class:

    package test;

    import com.sample.utils.LoggerUtils;

    public class Sample{
        LoggerUtils logger = LoggerUtils.getLogger(this.getClass());
        public void print(){
            logger.info("Hello");
        }
    }
```

In the log, I am getting :

```
2015-09-25 16:19:21,784 (test.Sample: info 27) - Hello
```

I am expecting something like :

```
2015-09-25 16:19:21,784 (test.Sample: print 8) - Hello
```

Comment: Any code you want to share?

Comment: My issue is similar to the one described in this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935367/log4j-class-name-showin-in-log-is-not-correct-when-i-call-the-logger-from-anoth

Just that I need to print method name and line number along with it

Comment: share the log4j.properties file.

Comment: log4j.appender.SampleLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.SampleLog.File=/sample.log

log4j.appender.SampleLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.SampleLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} (%c: %M %L) - %m%n

log4j.category.com.sample=DEBUG, SampleLog

Comment: You might want to put additions into your question rather than a comment. Makes it easier for others to see and easier to format.

Comment: updated with code details.

Comment: What is LoggerUtils' purpose anyway? My suggestion would be to just drop it.

Comment: Its purpose is that, when we need to change to some other loggers, we can easily do it with a single class change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the method and line that called your utility class, get the current stack trace and move up until you leave the code called by the utility class:

```
 StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
 for( StackTraceElement element : stackTrace ) {
    //ignore all entries from within LoggerUtils 
    if( element.getClassName().equalsIgnoreCase( LoggerUtils.class.getName() ) ) {
      continue;
    } else {
      String method = element.getMethodName();
      int lineNo = element.getLineNumber();
      break;
    }
 }
```